# Javascript Home Page Slider

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an onclick and an automatic slider for a website to test out my JavaScript skills. I have 4 images (of buttons) that when clicked calls a function. It changes the clicked image to a different image and the other 3 images become the unclicked buttons. It also changes the div above the images(of buttons). I do this by having 4 different divs stacked on top of each other and changing each's visability with JS. I had this working perfectly, but I wanted to take my slider to the next level, have it automatically switch from one div to the next after 5 seconds. Here is my current code.

```
function auto_change() {
if (document.getElementById("option1").style.visibility == 'visible'){
    setTimeout(change_2(),5000);
}
if (document.getElementById("option2").style.visibility == 'visible'){
    setTimeout(change_3(),5000);
}
if (document.getElementById("option3").style.visibility == 'visible'){
    setTimeout(change_4(),5000);
}
if (document.getElementById("option4").style.visibility == 'visible'){
    setTimeout(change_1(),5000);
}
}

 function change_1(x) {
document.getElementById("button1").src = "Images/button_current.png"; 
document.getElementById("button2").src = "Images/button_1.png";
document.getElementById("button3").src = "Images/button_1.png";
document.getElementById("button4").src = "Images/button_1.png";
document.getElementById("option1").style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById("option2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("option3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("option4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
auto_change();
 }
 function change_2(x) {
    document.getElementById("button2").src = "Images/button_current.png";
    document.getElementById("button1").src = "Images/button_1.png";
    document.getElementById("button3").src = "Images/button_1.png";
    document.getElementById("button4").src = "Images/button_1.png"; 
    document.getElementById("option1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("option2").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("option3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("option4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    auto_change();
  }
  function change_3(x) {

    document.getElementById("button3").src = "Images/button_current.png"; 
    document.getElementById("button1").src = "Images/button_1.png";
    document.getElementById("button2").src = "Images/button_1.png";
    document.getElementById("button4").src = "Images/button_1.png";
    document.getElementById("option1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("option2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("option3").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("option4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    auto_change();
   }
   function change_4(x) {

    document.getElementById("button4").src = "Images/button_current.png"; 
    document.getElementById("button1").src = "Images/button_1.png";
    document.getElementById("button2").src = "Images/button_1.png";
    document.getElementById("button3").src = "Images/button_1.png";
    document.getElementById("option1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("option2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("option3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("option4").style.visibility = 'visible';
    auto_change();
 }
```

My Idea is to have an onload in the body tag that calls auto_change(). Since the div with the id "option1" is visible it will delay for 5 seconds and then call change_2(). Then change_2() would run through its code and then call auto_change() again and you have a slow loop running. However, I can't seem to make the automatic sliding work out, any help?

Comment: Tip: Use common classes instead of id's and target elements by index; you can probably reduce the code to a few lines.

Comment: Before even looking, remove the () from your change_X() since they now all execute immediately. Then the next should be 10000, the third 15000 and so on

Comment: @elclanrs I could do that, make the code "beautiful", but currently I am working on making the code work and then simplifying the code. Yes, I know more work, but it makes the thought process easier on myself.

Comment: @mplungjan I always forget that! Thank you so much! It works now, I need to remember. I have run into this error a few times before and keep forgetting.

Comment: @Patrick: making the code beautiful or simple is not what this is about. Less lines of code means you can easily see its logic and/or where you went wrong. It's an integral part of coding, not a polishing step done as an afterthought.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the change_2 frunction and not all

```
function auto_change() {
if (document.getElementById("option1").style.visibility == 'visible'){
    setTimeout(change_2(),5000);
}
}
```

then in change_2 at last line call change_3 with timeout, same way in change_3 call to change_4  with timeout and in change_4 call to auto_change()

e.g.

```
function change_2(x) {
    //YOUR NORMAL CODE HERE AND ON LAST LINE

    setTimeout("change_3();",5000);
  }
```

Comment: Either `setTimeout(change_2,5000)` or `setTimeout(function() { change_2()},5000);`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var tId,idx=1, max=4; // can be more elegant by counting the buttons
function changeIt() {
  idx++; if (idx>max) idx=1;
  for (var i=1;i<=max;i++) {
    document.getElementById("button"+i).src = (idx==i)?"Images/button_current.png":"Images/button_1.png";
    document.getElementById("option"+i).style.visibility = (idx==i)?'visible':'hidden';
  }
}
window.onload=function() {
  tId=setInterval(changeIt,5000);
}
```